# Problem with enumerating formulas

Tags: logic, paradoxes

Let $P_0, P_1, P_2, ...$ be an enumeration of all logical formulas with one free variable $n$ (countable since they're finite strings of a countable alphabet). Let $Q(n) \iff \lnot P_n(n)$. For any $n$, $Q$ is not $P_n$ because they don't agree on $n$. But $Q$ is a logical formula so it *should* be in the enumeration...

What's going on?

Comment: How are you going to write $Q(n)$ as a single logical formula when it has to refer to infinitely many formulas $P_n$?

Comment: $P_n$ is a function which enumerates all strings that are valid logical formulas with one free variable $n$.

Comment: Just found a question asking the same thing: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2976937/where-is-the-mistake-in-this-proof-of-the-inconsistency-of-zfc

Comment: And the answers there point out the same problem that I did, but in much more detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will come down to the following: what is the precise definition of "logical formula?" The point is that although the $Q$ you've described is definitely "meaningful," it is of greater complexity in a sense than any of the $P_i$s. When we pin down a precise notion of "logical formula" and an enumeration of such, e.g.  "first-order formula in the language of arithmetic" ordered lexicographically via some reasonable ordering on the symbols involved, the corresponding $Q$ will turn out to not be expressible by a formula in that particular sense.

For a concrete example of how this plays out, see e.g. [Tarski's undefinability theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%27s_undefinability_theorem). And compare this to similar "paradoxes of expression:" Berry's paradox, Richard's paradox, and Grelling's paradox.

Answer (score 1):

It's important to distinguish between strings representing valid formulas and the formulas themselves.

See the following:

- [Richard's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard%27s_paradox) (the paradox and an explanation)
- [Tarski's undefinability theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%27s_undefinability_theorem) (there's no way to encode truth of a formula-string in a consistent logical system)
- [Godel's incompleteness theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_incompleteness_theorems) (provability can be encoded, but that's different from truth)